# How to display dynamic components in angular 8+

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9

I am new to Angular. I am working on a project where I want the administrator choose which components will be displayed to the user.

ps: In the admin interface, I have a "list" of components'names and when he choose one by checking it, it will be displayed in the user interface.

How Can I do this please?

Comment: does your components have routers for each and every one of em ?

Comment: yes they do have

Comment: are you familiar with Angular Router `canActivate' ?

Comment: I used it for the Authentication

Comment: you can use it to block routes too. that way i think you can archive what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Input() var1` and `@Output() var 2` to Input/Output a boolean and then control it in HTML using the `*ngIf` directive.

Then in HTML, use `[var1]` and `(var2)` to Input/Output.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can either display your dynamic components via,
template (using `*ngIf`) or
Programmatically (using `ViewContainerRef`)
Refer this article may help you.
https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-dynamically-create-a-component-in-angular